# What to know before getting a motherboard manufacture?

Tags: motherboard

I already have a motherboard for my device. Its a medical device, and the time when i get it manufactured, the manufacturer was unable to add some stuffs that was required.

Now i am in search for a new manufacturer... or may be different people specialized in different things. As i have talked to few people they are PCB designers, one is manufacturer and one will get all the components for the motherboard.

Firstly, is it good to get things done from different different people for different types of jobs, or should i look for some big company which can do all the stuff for me. Money is as usual constraint with me also.

Secondly, if i get the design work done from any designer... what actually his role in the project? Is only the implementation of idea onto boards with circuits or something else also?

I am stuck up with this work.... i have some ideas and i have a list of all my local designers and manufacturers, but i don't know how to start....

Please guide me, that i should know a bit before talking to them and also i could judge that they are genuine or not.

If any links would be given, which can help me understanding my problem, it would also be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I were you, I would start by hiring a consultant who has some experience getting boards contracted and built.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz At my place reasonable consultants also charge a lot.. And i personally need to do this, as the job is assigned to me by my boss.. i look after the IT department... and dont have very much idea about this field... hope you can understand..

Comment: You need someone who knows what they're doing who is loyal to you, not to any particular manufacturer. You can personally hire a qualified consultant. But this is not something you should fake. (If you go to a manufacturer without a consultant, it's near certain you'll wind up paying much more. They have no incentive to design a product that's cheap for you.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks, i think you really warning me before i get into any trouble... thanks... i'll find a good consultant for this work..

Comment: What is the name of the company you are working for?